# Trial user: BigQuery Reservation has 0 slot available for me all regions on GCP. How can I buy the slots?

Tags: google-bigquery, quota

Hi I am very new to GCP and making myself familiarized with the GCP environment. I am using trial credit at the moment.
I'm deploying "Item Matching" tutorial as the instructions go and I got stuck as I cannot buy any BigQuery slots to run the solution.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/analytics-componentized-patterns/tree/master/retail/recommendation-system/bqml-scann#set-up-the-gcp-environment

Has anyone got stuck at the same spot...?

[Please see the linked image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyJGZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increase the quota on the reservations API. Otherwise, you cannot buy slots. See attached image below:

[image]